# Can I get Apache (httpd.exe) error codes?

Tags: windows, apache, cmd

Basically I am trying to start `httpd.exe` from command prompt. So if any error occurs i should be able to catch the reason in codes, why it wasn't able to start. I know it already gives the exact reason but I want to display my own errors.
Is there any `error codes` like 0, 1, etc for httpd.exe.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Http Server is open source. If you want to know what error codes it returns, read the source code, which you can find by looking around in http://httpd.apache.org/. [The official doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html) does not specify any error codes, so YMMV.